# How can I smoothly transition from one property value to another?

Tags: css, css-transitions

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
img:hover {
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

This is my current code, and the current problem is that it looks unsmooth when the border-radius jumps to 20% from 50% on hover. I want it to be smoother like 50% to 49% to 48% to 47% all the way to 20%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for the [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property. *You even had the keyword in your question title!* ;)

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: border-radius 1s; /* HERE! */
}
img:hover {
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
```